# Strange behaviour in fromJSON in RJSONIO package

Tags: json, r, data-manipulation, rjsonio

Ok, I'm trying to convert the following JSON data into an R data frame.

For some reason fromJSON in the RJSONIO package only reads up to about character 380 and then it stops converting the JSON properly.

Here is the JSON:-

```
"{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-01\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"33682\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11838\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8023\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3815\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"84\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"177.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"177.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"237.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.50\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.68\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-02\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"32622\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11626\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7945\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3681\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"58\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"210.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"210.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"297.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.81\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"70.71\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-03\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"28467\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11102\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7786\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3316\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"56\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"186.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"186.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"261.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.68\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"71.26\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-04\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"20884\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9031\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6670\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2361\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"51\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"7.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"7.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"44.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.08\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"15.91\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-05\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"20481\",\"landCountTotal\":\"8782\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6390\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2392\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"58\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"1.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"1.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"8.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.01\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"12.50\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-06\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"25175\",\"landCountTotal\":\"10019\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7082\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2937\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"62\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"24.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"24.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"47.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.24\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"51.06\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-07\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"35892\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12615\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8391\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4224\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"62\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"239.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"239.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"321.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.89\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.45\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-08\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"34106\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12391\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8389\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4002\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"90\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"221.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"221.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"295.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.78\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.92\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-09\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"32721\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12447\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8541\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3906\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"54\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"280.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.66\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"73.93\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-10\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"29724\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11616\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8063\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3553\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"139\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"301.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.78\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"68.77\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-11\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"22061\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9660\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6971\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2689\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"52\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"3.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"3.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"40.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.03\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"7.50\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-12\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"23341\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9935\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6960\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2975\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"45\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"12.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.00\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"0.00\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-13\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"36565\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13583\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"9277\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4306\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"69\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"246.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"246.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"324.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.81\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"75.93\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-14\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"35260\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13797\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"9375\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4422\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"59\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"212.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"212.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"283.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.54\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.91\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-15\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"35836\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13792\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"9532\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4260\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"94\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"187.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"187.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"258.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.36\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"72.48\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-16\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"33136\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12821\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8755\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4066\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"65\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"192.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"192.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"260.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.50\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"73.85\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-17\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"29564\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11721\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8191\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3530\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"213\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"166.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"166.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"222.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.42\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.77\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-18\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"23686\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9916\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7335\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2581\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"56\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"5.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"5.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"34.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.05\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"14.71\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-19\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"23528\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9952\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7184\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2768\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"57\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"1.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"1.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"14.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.01\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"7.14\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-20\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"37391\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13488\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"9024\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4464\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"69\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"227.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"227.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"291.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.68\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"78.01\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-21\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"36299\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13174\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8817\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4357\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"77\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"164.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"164.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"221.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.24\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.21\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-22\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"34201\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12433\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8388\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4045\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"76\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"195.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"195.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"262.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.57\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.43\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-23\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"32951\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11611\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7757\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3854\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"68\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"167.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"167.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"231.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.44\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"72.29\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-24\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"28967\",\"landCountTotal\":\"10821\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7396\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3425\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"106\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"167.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"167.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"203.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.54\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"82.27\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-25\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"19741\",\"landCountTotal\":\"8393\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6168\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2225\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"78\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"28.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.00\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"0.00\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-26\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"19770\",\"landCountTotal\":\"8237\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6009\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2228\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"79\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"8.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.00\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"0.00\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-27\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"26208\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9755\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6779\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2976\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"82\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"26.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"26.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"40.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.27\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"65.00\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-28\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"36980\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12463\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8226\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4237\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"132\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"208.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"208.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"276.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.67\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"75.36\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-29\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"34190\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12014\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8279\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3735\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"90\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"179.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"179.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"235.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.49\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"76.17\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-30\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"33867\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11965\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8231\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3734\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"63\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"160.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"160.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"219.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.34\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"73.06\"}\n{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-31\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"27536\",\"landCountTotal\":\"10302\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7333\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2969\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"108\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"173.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"173.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"226.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.68\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"76.55\"}\n\r\n"
```

and here is my R output

```
 metricDate 
"2013-05-01" 
pageCountTotal 
"33682" 
landCountTotal 
"11838" 
newLandCountTotal 
"8023" 
returnLandCountTotal 
"3815" 
spiderCountTotal 
"84" 
goalCountTotal 
"177.000000" 
callGoalCountTotal 
"177.000000" 
callCountTotal 
"237.000000" 
onlineGoalCountTotal 
"0.000000" 
conversionPerc 
"1.50" 
callConversionPerc


"74.68\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-02\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"32622\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11626\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7945\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3681\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"58\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"210.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"210.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"297.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.81\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"70.71\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-03\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"28467\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11102\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7786\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3316\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"56\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"186.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"186.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"261.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.68\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"71.26\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-04\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"20884\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9031\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6670\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2361\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"51\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"7.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"7.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"44.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.08\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"15.91\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-05\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"20481\",\"landCountTotal\":\"8782\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6390\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2392\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"58\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"1.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"1.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"8.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.01\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"12.50\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-06\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"25175\",\"landCountTotal\":\"10019\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"7082\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2937\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"62\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"24.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"24.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"47.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.24\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"51.06\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-07\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"35892\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12615\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8391\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4224\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"62\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"239.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"239.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"321.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.89\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.45\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-08\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"34106\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12391\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8389\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4002\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"90\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"221.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"221.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"295.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.78\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.92\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-09\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"32721\",\"landCountTotal\":\"12447\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8541\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3906\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"54\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"280.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.66\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"73.93\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-10\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"29724\",\"landCountTotal\":\"11616\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"8063\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"3553\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"139\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"207.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"301.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.78\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"68.77\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-11\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"22061\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9660\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6971\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2689\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"52\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"3.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"3.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"40.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.03\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"7.50\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-12\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"23341\",\"landCountTotal\":\"9935\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"6960\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"2975\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"45\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"12.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"0.00\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"0.00\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-13\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"36565\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13583\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"9277\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4306\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"69\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"246.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"246.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"324.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.81\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"75.93\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-14\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"35260\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13797\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"9375\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4422\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"59\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"212.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"212.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"283.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.54\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"74.91\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-15\",\"pageCountTotal\":\"35836\",\"landCountTotal\":\"13792\",\"newLandCountTotal\":\"9532\",\"returnLandCountTotal\":\"4260\",\"spiderCountTotal\":\"94\",\"goalCountTotal\":\"187.000000\",\"callGoalCountTotal\":\"187.000000\",\"callCountTotal\":\"258.000000\",\"onlineGoalCountTotal\":\"0.000000\",\"conversionPerc\":\"1.36\",\"callConversionPerc\":\"72.48\"}{\"metricDate\":\"2013-05-
```

(I've truncated the output a little).

The R output has been read properly up until "callConversionPerc" and after that the JSON parsing seems to break. Is there some default parameter that I've missed that could couse this behaviour? I have checked for unmasked speechmarks and anything obvious like that I didn't see any.

Surely it wouldn't be the new line operator that occurs shortly after, would it?

**EDIT: So this does appear to be a new line issue.**

Here's another 'JSON' string I've  pulled into R, again the double quote marks are all escaped

```
"{\"modelId\":\"7\",\"igrp\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"Equally Weighted\",\"modelType\":\"spread\",\"status\":200,\"matchCriteria\":\"\",\"lookbackDays\":90}\n{\"modelId\":\"416\",\"igrp\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"First and Last Click Weighted \",\"modelType\":\"spread\",\"status\":200,\"matchCriteria\":\"\",\"lookbackDays\":90,\"firstWeight\":3,\"lastWeight\":3}\n{\"modelId\":\"5\",\"igrp\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"First Click\",\"modelType\":\"first\",\"status\":200,\"matchCriteria\":\"\",\"lookbackDays\":90}\n{\"modelId\":\"8\",\"igrp\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"First Click Weighted\",\"modelType\":\"spread\",\"status\":200,\"matchCriteria\":\"\",\"lookbackDays\":90,\"firstWeight\":3}\n{\"modelId\":\"128\",\"igrp\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"First Click Weighted across PPC\",\"modelType\":\"spread\",\"status\":200,\"matchCriteria\":\"\",\"lookbackDays\":90,\"firstWeight\":3,\"channelsMode\":\"include\",\"channels\":[5]}\n{\"modelId\":\"6\",\"igrp\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"Last Click\",\"modelType\":\"last\",\"status\":200,\"matchCriteria\":\"\",\"lookbackDays\":90}\n{\"modelId\":\"417\",\"igrp\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"Last Click Weighted \",\"modelType\":\"spread\",\"status\":200,\"matchCriteria\":\"\",\"lookbackDays\":90,\"lastWeight\":3}\n\r\n"
```

When I try to parse this using `fromJSON` I get the same problem, it gets to the last term on the first line and then stop parsing properly. Note that in this new case the output is slightly different from before returning `NULL` for the last item (instead of the messy string from the previous example.

```
$modelId
[1] "7"

$igrp
[1] "1"

$modelName
[1] "Equally Weighted"

$modelType
[1] "spread"

$status
[1] 200

$matchCriteria
[1] ""

$lookbackDays
NULL
```

As you can see, the components now use the "$" convention as if they are naming components and the last item is null.

I am wondering if this is to do with the way that `fromJSON` is parsing the strings, and when it is asked to create a variable with the same name as a variable that already exists it then fails and just returns a string or a NULL.

I would have thought that dealing with that sort of case would be coded into RJSONIO as it's pretty standard for JSON data to have repeating names.

I'm stumped as to how to fix this.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. You can check it by searching for JSON valdator on google.

Comment: being as I'm using a GET call to call the data in JSON format and then the fromJSON command in the RJSONIO package, would you have any idea why this would be happening? Would it be that the API I'm pulling it from is returning invalid JSON?

Comment: Looks like I can maybe get around it by gsubbing all of the "\" characters?

Comment: How are you actually getting the string into `fromJSON`? e.g., reading from file, cut-n-paste from console, assigned to variable and passed to function?

Comment: It is reading from a URL via a GET call (using `httr`). When I display the data as a webpage it does not have the offending backslashes. I tried gsub to remove the backslashes, but it made no difference! They were still there :(

Comment: So my code is `>fromJSON(contJSON)` where `contJSON` is the first object above. It seems that R adds the backslashes when pulling the data as the speechmarks are escape characters. This (I think) also causes problems with, for example the rGoogleAnalytics package.

Comment: Sorry, what am I saying? The speechmarks are special characters and so R escapes them, forgive me, I'm a dunce.

Comment: Writing `fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", gsub("\n", ",", contJSON)), asText=TRUE)` will make the JSON syntactically correct -- a single array of elements. `lapply(strsplit(sub("\r\n", "", contJSON), "\n"), fromJSON, asText=TRUE)` might be more-or-less equivalent but slower.

Comment: Both of these are telling me that `asText=TRUE` is an unused parameter. Removing this parameter in the first example throws an "unexpected character ','" error, although RStudio declines to tell me where. In the second removing this parameter returns the first line of the JSON as a list, but further values seem to be ignored.

Comment: You indicated that you were using RJSONIO, the current version `packageVersion("RJSONIO")` is 1.0.3. Maybe you're using the rjson library? If so, use `rjson::fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", gsub("\n", ",", sub("\n\r\n", "", contJSON))))`

Comment: This works. Consider putting it as a proper answer rather than hiding it in the comments? Yes I'm usinf RJSONIO 1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects of the JSON that seem to be causing trouble. The first is the trailing "\n\r\n", so get rid of that

```
contJSON = sub("\n\r\n$, "", contJSON)
```

The second is that the string is actually a series of valid JSON lines rather than a single JSON object. So either split it into valid JSON objects and process each individually

```
lapply(strsplit(contJSON, "\n"), fromJSON, asText=TRUE)
```

or create a string representing a single valid JSON object and process that

```
fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", gsub("\n", ",", contJSON)), asText=TRUE)
```

Both of these rely on details of the data so are not generally useful.

It's clear that `asText` is an argument for `fromJSON`

```
> args(RJSONIO::fromJSON)
function (content, handler = NULL, default.size = 100, depth = 150L, 
    allowComments = TRUE, asText = isContent(content), data = NULL, 
    maxChar = c(0L, nchar(content)), simplify = Strict, nullValue = NULL, 
    simplifyWithNames = TRUE, encoding = NA_character_, stringFun = NULL, 
    ...) 
NULL
```

So if R is complaining about an unused parameter it's likely that you're actually accessing a different function, in particular `rjson::fromJSON`. Perhaps `search()` shows that rjson appears before RJSONIO?

Comment: Great answer. Thankyou. I'm guessing one of the packages I load must import rJSON, maybe httr. I'll check it out tomorrow morning.